# AlpineJS async call to render array of objects

Tags: arraylist, async-await, alpine.js

Having the following snippet trying to fill an array of object with async alpine call but I can not get any result. Hier is what I try.

HTML:

```
  <div x-init="experts.retrieveList" x-data="experts.list">
    <ul>
    <template x-for="item in experts.list" :key="item">
      <li>
        <div x-text="await item.address" ></div>
      </li>
    </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

external JS file

```
window.experts = {
  apiUrl: 'http://bdb.local:8991/api/',
  data: [],
  list: [],
  expertsForm: null,
  retrieveList: () => {
    const membersUrl = `${experts.apiUrl}members?include=user,association,affiliate`;
    experts.apiCalls(membersUrl)
  },
  filterByParams: () => {

  },
  apiCalls: async (url) => {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    experts.list = await response.json()

    return experts.list;
  },
}
```

What is wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in this code:

- You cannot use just a part of an Alpine.js component in the `x-data="experts.list"`. If you don't define data variables directly in `x-data`, then it must be a real component that returns data and methods.
- You cannot use an object as the `key`. It must be a string or number, like `item.id` or something like this.
- The `x-text="await item.address"` seems incorrect. `item.address` should be a string, that has been already downloaded from the API.
- In the component you need to use the `this.` prefix to access properties and methods.

Assuming your API returns the correct data format, something like this should work:

```
<div x-data="experts">
  <ul>
    <template x-for="item in list" :key="item.id">
      <li>
        <div x-text="item.address"></div>
      </li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the component in an external file:

```
const experts = {
    apiUrl: 'http://bdb.local:8991/api/',
    data: [],
    list: [],
    expertsForm: null,

    init() {
        const membersUrl = `${experts.apiUrl}members?include=user,association,affiliate`
        this.apiCalls(membersUrl)
    },

    filterByParams() {

    },

    async apiCalls(url) {
        let response = await fetch(url)
        this.list = await response.json()
    },
}
```

The `init()` method is executed automatically by Alpine.js.

Comment: Hi @Dauros thanks a lot for this clearings. I have tried the code what you suggested. Needed to add as window object the constant because I did not had access to it. The request call is all ok and the object variables are getting initialized but in frontend I do not have access to the list variable. Testing like `<div x-data="experts">
  <script>console.log(list)</script>` I `get ReferenceError:list is not defined` what can cause this issue?

Comment: Here `list` is a property inside an Alpine.js component, so we can access them within Alpine.js context. You can use e.g. `<div x-effect="console.log(list)"></div>` to log it when it changes.

Comment: Thanks again, this works as expected it will show the data in console on state update, but `<template x-for="item in list" :key="item.id">` is not getting triggered in this case. I have to use some kind of observer in this case?

Comment: sorry is all fine works! Thanks a lot